# Как правильно сделать переход между четырьми страницами с использованем BottomNavigationView или ActionBar в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbar, bottom-navigation-view

Добрый день. Прошу строго не судить за неправильные названия некоторых вещей, я ещё совсем зелёный в Android разработке. 
В чём суть проблемы? Я хочу сделать переход между несколькими разными элементами экрана(например, на первом карта, но втором пара кнопок и текст вью и т.д).
Дайте подсказку, как это сделать(код писать не надо, просто скиньте название и статью об этом методе).

[image]

Comment: у боттом навигейшна есть два лиснера setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener и Reselected соответственно. В них переклчайте фрагменты

Comment: Благодарю! Сейчас ещё кое-что посмотрю и попробую сделать!

Comment: Есть очень хорошая статья про [Bottom Navigation View](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/bottom-navigation-android-example/) Мне очень помогло, надеюсь и тебе тоже!)

Comment: сделать это можно [как то так](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=bottomnavigationview%20android)